# Hibernate logging in Spring application on JBoss 7.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, log4j

I have Spring MVC application integrated with Hibernate.

I'm trying to log jdbc SQL statement parameters using Log4j but it doesn't work. It seems like my log4j.properties configuration file does not make any changes. Here is project config:

I'm using Maven, Eclipse and log4j.properties file is at the top of the projects source folder (so as I understand in the classpath).

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <org.hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
    <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.0</slf4j-log4j12.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

log4j.logger.main.mvc.model.hibernate=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. So I finally got it working!

All these troubles were caused by JBoss AS 7.1.

So here is how to set up slf4j+log4j logging on Spring MVC application that is run on JBoss AS 7.1:

1. There are built-in JBoss modules that has to be turneda off so - add **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** to your **META-INF/** directory
2. You have to have these libraries in classpath: **log4j.jar**, **slf4j-api.jar**, **slf4j-log4j12.jar**, **jcl-over-sfl4j.jar**. Spring's default **common-logging.jar** has to be excluded from classpath.
3. You have to have **log4j.properties** or **log4j.xml** file in classpath.

These files gave me control over logs and I achieved my goal - logging Hibernate SQL statement parameters.

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bladositto</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestLogging</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <org.hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
    <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.0</slf4j-log4j12.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1, R

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this in your log4j config

```
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=INFO
org.hibernate=INFO
org.springframework.orm=DEBUG,stdout
```

Whereas it should be

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm=DEBUG,stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` or in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Plus the following inside your `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x - %m%n

org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=INFO
org.hibernate=INFO
org.springframework.orm=DEBUG,stdout
```

I have no doubt you will have logs if you put these two files in the classpath of your webapp.

With Maven, you should put these files inside the folder `src/main/resources`. They will be packaged inside the resulting `target` folder you will get if you do a 'mvn clean package`.

To declare a slf4j logger, you should do this way:

```
public class User {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);

    //fields getters and setters...

    public User() {

    }

    public User(DTO userDTO) {
        this.username = userDTO.username;
        // etc.
        logger.debug("your user was initialized with the DTO, see this.toString()=?", this.toString());
    } 


    //etc. some other methods, if any

    //toString()
    public String toString() {
        //return a String representation of an User object.
    }
}
```

And to limit a log level for a specific appender, you should use:

```
log4j.logger.appenderName.packageName.className=LEVEL
```

Note you are currently using:

```
log4j.logger.packageName.className=LEVEL
```

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My pom.xml file is ok, right?  I've put log4j.properties file to src/main/resources. In class *UserService* in package *services* there is a line `Logger.getLogger(getClass()).info(user);`  which results in    `20:46:52,449 INFO  [services.UserService] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) User[id: null loginEmail: null alias: Asdf password: asdfasdfasdf]`  Then I tried to limit it with *log4j.logger.services.UserService=WARN* in log4j.properties but it still shows up in logs. It seems like this file is still not used by log4j

Comment: You have added the `slf4j` dependency in your `pom.xml` so it is possible that slf4j is used with default configuration. See edited response to have an example of slf4j usage inside a java class.

Comment: Ok. That was great tip to use SLF4J logger instead of LOG4J's one. Although it still have not gained control over logging. Its driving me nuts. I'm starting to wonder if it's not my application servers fault? I'm using JBoss AS 7.